# Correct to import module class python

Tags: python, class, import, module

Python project structure:

```
src/
  - package-name/
     -- A/
         ---B/
               b1.py
         ---C/
               c1.py
```

In `c1.py`, it uses a function defined in `b1.py`. I try 2 ways:

Method1: `from src.package-name.A.B.b1 import b1_func`
Method2: `from ..B.b1 import b1_func`

The import module starts from `package-name` directory, so `src/` will not be visible in the imported module. So Method1 not working when import my own module.

Method2 is not working when run in IDE. `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `__init__.py` files in A and B? It may be worthwhile to properly import  b1_func into B's and then A's init files.

B `__init__.py`

```
from .b1_file import b1_func
```

or whatever

and A `__init__.py`

```
from B import b1_func
```

Then you should be able to `import ..b1_func`

Answer (score 0):

I change the "Content Root" to the package-name directory in PyCharm and `import package-name.B.b1`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps to import the packages wherever u want

1. First of all, add __init__.py in all folders

**i.e**:  `__init__.py in src` and `__init__.py in package` and `__init__.py in A`
and `__init__.py in B` and `__init__.py in C`.

2. If u want to import the functions from `b1.py` in `c1.py` add these lines in `c1.py` file.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(“../”)

#if u want from src folder add ../../

from B.b1 import YourFunctionName
```